# Order and similarity measurement

Tags: clustering, pattern-recognition

Let's say I have 10 different groups, and each group has its own string sequence. So, it should be like:

```
G1 -> CHFAIEBD
G2 -> HCFJIGBD
G3 -> HCFAIJBD
G4 -> HFCIJEBD
G5 -> .....
```

The question is: **is there a statistical test to say that the ordering in that 10 groups is similar?** I know it looks kind of similar, but I don't know how to prove it statistically. I really appreciate your comment on this.

Comment: One method would be Hamming distance. Pick one row. Assign every other row a value of 0, then add 1 to its value for each character that is different in the respective position. For example, the comparison of "THEN" and "THEM" has a Hamming distance of 1, because the last letter is different, while both "THEM" and "THEN" have a Hamming distance of 4 from the word "BOTH" because all letters are different.

Comment: But with your method, we can only compare two groups, not the whole 10 groups. Do you think this Hamming distance can be used to compare them simultaneously ?

Comment: You can build a square matrix comparing each group to each other group, where the value in each cell is the distance between a pair. Then you can examine all of the pairwise distances, and state that distance is mostly some value, or all distances are below some other value.

Comment: Levensthein distance is another distance metric, now that I think about it.

Comment: Are all of these "words" compose of the same set of letters? Because then you might consider taking as a distance the smallest number of letter swaps between two "words" as the distance.

Comment: Yeah, each group is composed of A B C ... till J. What do you mean by the number of letter swaps between two words ?

Comment: For example, "ABC" is one swap from "BAC" because you exchange the position of A and B.

Comment: Does your question have a thing with _statistical testing_, or not, after all? Do you want some p-value, what is your null-hypothesis? What is the alternative, then?

Comment: Hi, I'm testing whether the order of sequences from that 10 groups is different or not. It doesn't have to be p-value, as long as I can find a way to formally (or mathematically) quantify the similarity (or diversity) in the order.